# Exclude some records from aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions, database-partitioning

Having this piece of SQL code:

```
MIN([Price]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Brand], [Article]) AS MinPrice,
```

Question: how to exclude from `MIN()` some records, where a.e. `[Supplier] != 10`?

Answer (score 3):

Add `WHERE [Supplier] != 10` to your query.

Comment: I said **query**. `SELECT MIN([Price]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Brand], [Article]) AS MinPrice FROM Table WHERE [Supplier] != 10`

Comment: Have problems again, so better that I'll show my code:
  `SELECT TOP 1000 p.*
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             MIN([SDA_COST]) OVER (PARTITION BY [SDA_BRA_ID], [SDA_ART_ID]) AS MinPrice,
    MIN([SDA_COST]) OVER (PARTITION BY [SDA_BRA_ID], [SDA_ART_ID])  AS MinConcPrice  
      FROM  [autoparts_portal].[dbo].[CI_SUP_DATA]  p
     ) p
where [SDA_SUP_ID] = 10 AND
      ([SDA_COST] < 0.98 * MinConcPrice OR [SDA_COST] != MinPrice);

   
  GO`

Comment: I'm just need to exclude record with specified Supplier from MIN function on each group or do any other checking logic.

Comment: used this code: `SELECT TOP 1000 p.*
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             MIN([Price]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Brand], [Article]) AS MinPrice,
    (SELECT MIN([Price]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Brand], [Article]) FROM [autoparts_portal].[dbo].[CI_SUP_DATA] WHERE [Supplier] != 10) AS MinConcPrice 
    FROM  [autoparts_portal].[dbo].[CI_SUP_DATA]  p
     ) p
where [SDA_SUP_ID] = 10 AND
      ([Price] < 0.98 * MinConcPrice OR [Price] > MinPrice);

   
  GO`  
<br/><br/>
Got error "nested query returns more than one value"

Comment: The subquery `(SELECT MIN([Price]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Brand], [Article]) FROM [autoparts_portal].[dbo].[CI_SUP_DATA] WHERE [Supplier] != 10)` is going to return more than one row.  That's what it's complaining about, I suspect.  Subqueries that you include in a SELECT clause (as opposed to the FROM clause) have to return one value only.